# Python script won't run from the command line. It shows no error

Tags: python, cmd, command-line, conda, environment

I'm trying to run a simple Python Script on the CMD but nothing happens when I run it. I get no errors or anything. The py script is just a simple print ("Hello World").

All my .py files are in the Python/Projects file.

http://puu.sh/FFfJm/ee63955506.png

Just some context regarding this: 
I did install Python then Pycharm then Anaconda. I don't know if that has anything to do with conflicting Python files.

Comment: Rename the program to be `Hello_World.py" and then run `python Hello_World.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python` isn't in your path. Checkout [Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows), which is a good reference to the question of adding a variable to the path in CMD.

Comment: These file names aren’t mentioned in the question, right?

Comment: I've amended the screenshot to now say Hello World.py which is an actual py file with just a simple print statement. Still nothing prints.

If I go back to D:\Python on the CMD where my python.exe is located, typing python -- version outputs "Python 3.8.0"

Comment: What does `python --version` output in the directory where your program files are?

Comment: Try `D:\Python\python.exe "Hello World.py"`

Comment: That command actually works! Thanks but i'm still baffled as to why it's not executing using the simple python command in CMD.

Comment: You need to add python to your path. Here's an excellent StackOverflow answer explaining it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows

Comment: Prior to posting this, I actually did make a PATH variable to D:\Python\Projects using the environment variables. Still doesn't work but I'll try restarting my computer to see if anything changes.

Comment: You need to make the path variable `D:\Python` if `python.exe` is in `D:\Python`

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much, me setting the PATH variable to D:\Python where my python.exe works. Now I can type Python "Hello.World.py" and it will now execute the script. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you entered your command line query correctly?

```
python python_file_name.py
```

If you just entered your `file_name.py` it might have executed it but ended it simultaneously before you could see any result.

also try putting your file_name in double quotes.

Comment: Hi, I inputted on cmd as "python Hello World.py" and nothing shows up. I also tried the double quotes but still no results.

Comment: When you type python on cmd does it display the python console?

Comment: If I type python in the directory where my python.exe is located (D:\Python), it will execute the Python Interpreter. However If i type it anywhere else, it will open my Microsoft Windows Store for some reason.

Comment: Did you create a virtual environment as save the virtual environment python as your default Python?

Comment: Just try reinstalling python from the official python site - python.org. Also add python to your path while installing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python in PATH but script execution still doesn't  work, inspect the C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps folder.

There might be a zero-size python.exe file. It seems that this folder is earlier in PATH and zero-byte file intercept the console command execution. The microsoft store is opened with python page if I run that file.
I removed this folder and python script start working again.

You also can ensure the correct python is available to the terminal with 'where python' to see the full path.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, you'd need to call

```
python "Hello World.py"
```

**with quotes**, *not*

```
python Hello World.py  // no, won't work
```

The reason is, when you don't include quotes around a filename with a space, it only takes the FIRST thing you wrote as the script name, the rest of the "words" are just passed as "command line arguments"